# ROR: Can i put a little logic to select data and do looping on .rake file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

```
namespace :test do
  desc "Update data"
  task :update_data => :environment do
    datas = Model.where(approved: true)
    datas.each do |data|
      SomeService.call(data)
    end
  end
end
```

I need task to udpate multiple data to run using cronjob (whenever gem). Can I do something like the code above? If yes, is this the right way or there are a better options?

The service can be called via controller too (only update 1 data), that's why I need something like this (put the looping outside the service).

Comment: Are you asking whether you should do this or if this will actually work?

Comment: Whether I should do this or not

Comment: I don't see why not, it is perfectly good code.

Comment: I see, thank you then. I'm new to ruby so I just a little hesitant.

Comment: Just one hint, if you're dealing with large amounts of data using `find_each`. will load data in batches, instead of all at once, helping performance but mainly reducing memory load. `Model.where(approved: true).find_each do |data|`

Comment: I see, this is new to me, thank u very much, this will surely help